# how to enable advanced streaming functionalities in webots R2019a

Tags: webots

I am setting up a new webots environment using AWS instances and docker. I did the set up using a VNC Server but I think the new --stream option (in webots R2019a) is exactly what I need to access the webots GUI interface for my application.

I checked the documentation and it says that is possible to: "The sample Javascript we provide to communicate with Webots supports advanced features that are not available during the basic broadcast streaming. This includes controlling the execution of the simulation, modifying the Python robot controller program and displaying the robot windows. All these functionalities are enabled when starting the streaming using the simulation_server.py and session_server.py script located at WEBOTS_HOME/resources/web/server."

So, I am trying to enable (locally):

1. control the execution of the simulation interactively
2. add my controller to the editor to modify interactively

But i am having trouble finding the right place to modify simulation_server.py and session_server.py. Any additional documentation or guide up on how can I achieve that?

What I tried until now: I created my docker image and i am able to run webots in my server using the 'stream' flag, but I can't control my simulation because the menu is disable as the following image:

[Webots Streaming Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkPIp.png)

**EDIT(SOLUTION)**: After revising especially the webots.js file, I see that the buttons are disabled because view.broadcast is set to True. Therefore, to solve the problem I set view.broadcast to False in the connect() function in setup_viewer.js. Now I will do additional tests to check if it has any additional bugs.

However, I am still revising on how to enable to edit controllers or configuration files using the web GUI.

Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. For more information, please see
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-as

Comment: Did you read this documentation? https://github.com/omichel/webots/tree/master/resources/web

Comment: Hi Fabien. Yes, i checked the documentation, but it seems to be outdated as the json files and the projects folder do not exist. I think I should create a new json configuration file for my application, but dont know how. I also checked this documentation: github.com/omichel/webots/tree/master/resources/web/server . It was helpful but not sufficient to give a hint on how I can enable the advanced options.